# Regex to extract number from string (gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name

Tags: regex, powershell, wmi

I'm using (gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name to get the operating system version so a configuration script can choose the appropriate variables file based on that version. However, I want to be specific as possible. I want to restrict the OS version to just the OS number (i.e. 7 for Windows 7, 8 for Windows 8, 2012 for Windows Server 2012, etc). Here is what I have so far:

```
(gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name
```

produces:

```
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4
```

When I try to restrict it to just numbers with this:

```
(gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name -replace '\D+(\d+)\D+','$1'
```

I get:

```
100\Partition4
```

I need the output to just be "10". How can I adjust my regex statement to only select the 10 (or 7, or 2012)? I thought about somehow restricting the regex to stop processing the string after the first encountered number block (i.e. hit a number and then stop when you hit a space) but I haven't the foggiest idea how to do such a thing. Or perhaps there is an even better way to get the information I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about splitting on space and getting the right item in the array? `((gwmi win32_operatingsystem).name).split(" ")[2]`

Comment: Lieven, that worked perfectly and it was so simple. If you don't mind me asking, what does the [2] accomplish? If you post this as the answer, I'll mark it accordinglt.

Comment: The split turns the string into an array *(drop the [2])* to view the entire contents. The [2] is merely the index in the array. Not sure to post this as an answer because I'm not sure about this being foolproof for every version of windows.

Comment: You are correct. It works fine for 7, 8 and 10, but returns "Server" for 2012. Still a great answer, so thank you for that and the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This outputs "10" :

```
'Microsoft Windows 10 Pro|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4' -replace '.*\s(\d+)\s.*','$1'
```

`.*` : any character (`.`) 0 or more times (`*`)

`\s` : a space

`\d+` : a digit (`\d`) 1 or more times (`+`)

Comment: That works great! I tried it on Windows 10, 7 and 2012 and it gave the correct output. Do you mind me asking how this works? It seems that you are selecting the numbers (\d+) inside of a string (the .*\s and \s.*). Is that correct?

Comment: Awesome. So let me make sure I've got this correct. The regex finds anything with any character, followed by a space, then any length set of digits with a space after and any character after? Something like [asterisk]sdddds[asterisk]?

Comment: That's a way to put it, yes

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the Name property of the win32_operatingsytem class you should go for either the Caption or the Version property of the class.
See the difference in these 3 properties in the win32_operatingsystem class :

```
name    : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk3\Partition1
caption : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
version : 10.0.10586
```

It's much easier to parse the caption or the version.
To be honest : I'd always go for the 'version' because it also contains the buildnumber.

Comment: +1 although `version` is the *kernel version*. The major version will be `6` for all versions of Windows Vista/2008 through 8.1/2012 R2. Better parse the `Caption` property if you want output like 7, 10, 2012 or 8.1 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing everything after the first `|`, you don't need that:

```
$OSName,$null = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Name.Split("|")
```

Then apply the regex -replace to the resulting string:

```
$OSVersion = $OSName -replace '\D+(\d+)\D*','$1'
```

Comment: Great suggestion, Mathias. That works, but both sodawillow and Lieven gave simpler answers. Your answer was helpful thought because I learned more about the split operation. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways of doing this would be the following:

```
(gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name -replace "(Harddisk.*)|(Partition.*)|([a-z])|(\\)|(\|)|(:)"
```

The way this works is by first replacing all the data after `Harddisk` or `Partition`, next we remove all letters and special characters (`\` or `|`).

After that, all we're left with is numbers and dots.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the the string returned in the Version property to a [System.Version] object by using the [version] accelerator.  This returns an object containing integer representations of the Major, Minor, Build and Revision numbers:

```
[version](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
```

or to get only the Major number:

```
([version](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version).Major
```